# How to remove rows that meet certain certain criteria in R

Tags: r, for-loop, subset

I have data from simulations of a population model where I have multiple replicates(run_num) with an unequal number of time steps in each run where I measure outputs of length and eggs (phys_length & no_eggs).

```
> head(params)
  run_num time_step phys_length no_eggs
1       1         0 0.000000000       0
2       1         1 0.008209734       0
3       1         2 0.016332967       0
4       1         3 0.024238314       0
5       1         4 0.031594308       0
6       1         5 0.033077672       0

> tail(params)
       run_num time_step phys_length no_eggs
607395      49     13728    15.04109     727
607396      49     13729    15.04111     727
607397      49     13730    15.04112     727
607398      49     13731    15.04113     727
607399      49     13732    15.04114     727
607400      49     13733    15.04115     727
>
```

None of the the runs produce eggs in the early time steps (non-mature individuals), but some never begin to produce eggs. I want to find all the instances where the individual (run) never begins to produce eggs and remove that entire run from the dataframe.  My solution is to find the max time_step for each run and if no_eggs=0 remove that entire run.

I'm an R newbie and have no idea where to begin to actually instruct R to do that. I'm thinking a for loop, but I get stuck when trying to figure out how to tell R to only look at the max time_step in each run. Then how to remove all rows that have that run_number.

This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure if I am on the right track, since I've never worked with for-loops before now.

```
for (val in params$run_num)) {
  if(no_eggs   )
}
```

Any ideas on how to do this are appreciated.

Comment: You need to look for subsetting dataframes, come back to us if you're still stuck (but what you're trying to do is relatively easy) you don't need a for loop.

Comment: what is the expected outcome?

Comment: The expected outcome is to get a dataframe with only the individuals (1 run = life cycle of 1 individual) that are viable (start to produce eggs at some point in their life cycle). The eventual goal is to be able to plot average egg production over time, but because of the nature of our energetics model we get these non-viable individuals that mess up my averages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to proceed:

- construct a subset of your data frame consisting of the nonzero entries of `no_eggs`
- strip out all the `num_run` entries corresponding to those vectors
- subset the original data frame based on the good `num_run` entries found above

Your data set isn't reproducible, so I can't test this code, but something like this should work:

```
params2 <- params[params$run_num %in% unique(params[params$no_eggs > 0, ]$run_num), ]
```

To understand the logic, let's look from the inside out:

- `params[params$no_eggs > 0, ]$run_num` takes the `params` data frame and subsets it based on the rows which have `no_eggs > 0`, then strips the `run_num` vector from that subset
- `unique(...)` records a list of the unique elements found in the above, which is a list of the `run_num`s we wish to keep
- `params[params$run_num %in% ..., ]` makes another subset of `params`, keeping only the rows with `run_num` entries found in the list we built above using `unique()`

Comment: I don't think this approach will work because initially none of the individuals produce eggs (they are not mature in the early time steps) so I can't just remove all the runs that have a zero in the no_eggs column.

Comment: This will exclude only the `num_row` values for which there is *only* a zero in the `no_eggs` column. I think that's what you want; please let me know if I'm mistaken!

Comment: Let me rephrase a bit: there are two subsetting operations in play in this solution. The first throws out all rows with `no_eggs == 0`, but only for the purpose of building a list of the "good" `run_num`s. Once we have that list, we do a second subsetting operation where we keep the rows (from the original data frame) with the "good" `run_num`s. This will have the effect of keeping the `run_num`s where `no_eggs` starts at zero but eventually becomes nonzero.

Comment: Ahh! I understand now. That should work. I'll give it a try. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

in the begining R can be a bit hard to understand, this is how i would do it in base R

```
#your data
run_num <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,49,49,49,49,49,49)
timestep <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,13728,13729,13730,13731,13732,13733)
phys_length <- c(0.000000000,0.008209734,0.016332967,0.024238314,0.031594308,0.033077672,15.04109,15.04111,15.04112,15.04113,15.04114,15.04115)
eggs <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,727,727,727,727,727,727)

params <- as.data.frame(cbind(run_num,timestep,phys_length,eggs))


#this line returns a vector of True and False we can use this to grab all the rows where the statement is true
params$eggs == 0 

#like here "params[,]" is your whole data frame, and in the "[,]" the first value is row number, and second is colunm number
#if set like below it returns all rows that were true, and since the second value was empty it returns all columns

no_eggs <- params[params$eggs == 0,]
```

Update: this will give you the run numbers that produce eggs,

```
#find all runs with eggs
eggs <- params[params$eggs != 0,]

# grab run number and make it unique 
run <- unique(eggs[1])

#return all rows that result in runs with eggs greater than 0
cleaned_df <- params[eggs$run_num == run,]
```

Comment: i think i understand, the question better now, thank you.  this was my best guess with such a small dataset :), update inc

Comment: Yes that is the case. I do not know how to make a better dataset available since the full data set has over 1 million observations.

Comment: updated, if i missed somthing please point it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider `ave` for an inline aggregate by *Run* grouping, then subset by flagged observations via logical conditions using `ifelse`:

```
# INLINE AGGREGATE
params$max_time_step <- with(params, ave(time_step, run_num, FUN=max))

# FLAG COLUMN
params$max_time_no_eggs <- with(params, ifelse(time_step == max_time_step & no_eggs == 0, 1, 0))

# EXPAND FLAG TO ENTIRE run_num GROUP
params$max_time_no_eggs <- with(params, ave(max_time_no_eggs, run_num, FUN=max))

# SUBSET OUT FLAGGED RECORDS
sub_params <- subset(params, max_time_no_eggs == 0)

# DROP HELPER COLUMNS
params$max_time_step <- NULL
params$max_time_no_eggs <- NULL

sub_params$max_time_step <- NULL
sub_params$max_time_no_eggs <- NULL
```

Or two lines using context managers, `within` and `transform`:

```
sub_params <- within(params,  {
    # INLINE AGGREGATE
    max_time_step <- ave(time_step, run_num, FUN=max)
    # FLAG COLUMN
    max_time_no_eggs <- ifelse(time_step == max_time_step & no_eggs == 0, 1, 0) 
    # EXPAND FLAG TO ENTIRE run_num GROUP
    max_time_no_eggs <- ave(max_time_no_eggs, run_num, FUN=max)
})

sub_params <- transform(subset(params, max_time_no_eggs == 0),
                        max_time_step = NULL,
                        max_time_no_eggs = NULL)
```